# What film and developer did Harold Feinstein use?

Tags: film, photographer, developer

Although [Harold](https://www.haroldfeinstein.com/blog/) has written/taught various topics on photography
and printing, I can't seem to find what film and developer did he use, 
especially for his Coney Island series.

Perhaps others can shed a light?

Comment: Unless it's documented it's unlikely anyone knows.  In addition what *paper* he used & how he made the prints is probably more important (and the answer to that will certainly be 'a paper you can no longer get').

Comment: For any shooter who has had a long and lively career, I'd expect their film and paper choices to evolve or change. I would consider asking about all photos to be too broad a question anyway. Can this question be limited to a single image?

Answer (score 1):

On his [web site](https://www.haroldfeinstein.com), in a comment on the post [Available light: Coney Island at Night](https://www.haroldfeinstein.com/about-this-photo-watching-the-gyro-coney-island-1949/) Harold Feinstein has supported pushing TRI-X (from 200 to 1600) by developing with Diafine for low light photography.